# File does not exist: /home/mysite/public_html/A2EB891D63C8

Tags: apache-2.2

In my apache error_logs I am getting this error repeatedly. 
[Tue Jul 26 16:45:07 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/mysite/public_html/A2EB891D63C8

I think it might have lead to some heavy server load.

Googleing it looks like: A2EB891D63C8 has something to do with AVG antivirus

Any ideas what this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone's probably just probing your system, looking for files which might indicate a vulnerability.  You can ignore them; they're almost certainly not contributing in any measurable way to server load, as individual requests.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the purpose of this is that AVG injects a script into the DOM of each page the user's browser visits in hopes of detecting potentially harmful content in the websites the user is browsing.

I'm not sure why exactly the error occurs, but I believe it has something to do with url rewrites breaking the script injection.

I know on my application we rewrite all urls and I see these errors all the time and hasn't proven to be harmful in any way.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is true.